# UIGlassButton in iOS 6/on iPhone 5 not working

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uikit, uiglassbutton

I am trying to use the UIGlassButton on my iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1 final. There are no errors, just that the UIGlassButton doesn't show up. I also tried [this](https://github.com/hamrickdavid/UIGlassButton-Creator/tree/master/GlassButtonCreator) and many other yet finished GlassButton proects on GitHub etc., but none of them works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the reason why you shouldn't use private API's. Because classes like these are for internal use only, they could change or even be removed in between OS updates.

Imagine you would have used this in an application already in the store, it would either crash or just not show the buttons. A good way to treat your users.

`UIGlassButton` is a private class and should not be used. To create a similar effect build the button yourself or use images.